# Using a character array to colour scatterplot points in matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, scatter-plot

I have some vectors I am plotting in a scatter plot:
x, y, and z.

I plot these vectors using the scatter3 function.

scatter3(x, y, z)

This now provides me with my scatterplot correctly.  However, all points are blue, and I need to colour some of the points different colours.

To this end I have a vector 'colours'.  Colours is the same length as x, y, and z.  Colours is a character array, consisting of the different characters for colours in matlab, such as 'b' for blue, 'r' for red', and so on.

//A small example: colours == 'bbbbbyyyrrr'

I realise I can probably loop through all points and recolor after plotting.  However, the simulations produce large vectors, and this is very inefficient with time.

Is there a way to use the colours vector to colour the points such that the point given by x(3), y(3), z(3), would be of colour colours(3)?

Comment: Use `scatter3(x,y,z,[],c)` where `c` is a vector where, for example, 1 corresponds to `'b'`, 2 to `'c'`, etc. then set up a custom colormap for the colours. `c` can also be an `n` by 3 matrix of RGB values for each data point.

Comment: @David What do you mean by setting up a custom colormap?  I read the colormap documentation with the example

mymap = [0 0 0
    1 0 0
    0 1 0
    0 0 1
    1 1 1];


I understand these are the rgb triplets, and also that I can convert from char to rgb triplet.  However, to set up a custom colormap I assume you call colormap(mymap) -- how does this affect the scatter function when it's taking chars as an input?

Without setting up a custom colormap, I get the error "Error in color/linetype argument".

Answer (score 0):

Build a `Map` object to map characters to rgb values (based on [this table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html)), then given a vector of characters you can read the rgb values from the map:

```
cmap = containers.Map({'y','m','c','r','g','b','w','k'},{[1 1 0],[1 0 1],[0 1 1],[1 0 0],[0 1 0],[0 0 1],[1 1 1],[0 0 0]});
cols = 'bbbbbyyyrrr';
rgb_vals = cell2mat(values(cmap,cellstr(cols(:))));
scatter3(1:11,1:11,1:11,[],rgb_vals)
```

The `values` function gets the values of the specified keys, and `cell2mat` converts the cell array which is the output of `values` back to a matrix which `scatter3` can handle.